# How do you use basic_auth for all but one route using Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, nginx, basic-authentication, laravel-forge

I am using the in-built HTTP basic access authentication for Laravel Forge.
I am currently using basic_auth for all routes.
I would like to exclude one route (basic_auth off).

I tried to customise the file, example: /etc/nginx/forge-conf/.../server/.htpasswd-{ruleId}

I added the following additional code:

```
location = /example {
    basic_auth off;
}
```

I also tried:

```
location /example {
    basic_auth off;
}
```

I restarted nginx. I restarted the server. Same result: no change. The route /example was not excluded from basic_auth.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a solution using the in-built "Security" tool for basic authentication provided by Laravel Forge.

I was able to solve the problem by updating the nginx file for the site without using the aforementioned "Security" tool.

Replace [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with your site address on Laravel Forge.
Replace /example with the path that you would like to exclude.

```
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/forge/www.example.com/.htpasswd;
       
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
    
location /example {
    auth_basic off;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I created a .htpasswd file (search Google to find out how to generate your own with a username and password). I uploaded it to the root of my project directory, at the same level as the .env file.